# htaccess redirect by folder AND extension with cap variations

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Doing a conversion that involves an old windows site to a new CMS setup - and due to many inbound links to pdfs/images that they do NOT want to have rerouted (for their own reasons), there are some folder/files that will remain from the old setup containing certain pdfs/images.

Of course caps wasn't an issue with windows, but is with linux - and also, a couple of the root folders in question have the same name as root permalinks in the new site.

So, these rewrites need to be specifically targeted at certain files/folders, but also take into account potential missed capitalization.

For example, there is a folder called Industries (with capital I), and on the new system, a permalink for 'industries' (small i).

So, as long as exact url's are submitted, it is fine - site.com/industries (small i) pulls up correct page in CMS, and site.com/Industries/whatever.pdf (capital I) pulls up a pdf document from the lefover Industries folder.

The problem is that some inbound links are: site.com/industries/whatever.pdf (no cap), or even site.com/INDUSTRIES/whatever.pdf (all caps - yep that's right)

Of course without the capital I - these are then failing in the CMS as a 404.

So, I am trying to create a rewrite rule that targets ONLY the file types: pdf, jpg and png - and ONLY when being access through certain specific folders.  In addition, it needs to take into account at least the primary spelling variations seen to avoid the 404s - and of course, if there is no match it should just abort and move on so that it can be process by the cms.

Where I am at so far, using example of existing folder: Industrial

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)industrial(.*(jpg|png|pdf))$ OR
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)INDUSTRIAL(.*(jpg|png|pdf))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1Industrial%2 [L,R=301]
```

Hopefully you can see what I am trying to do, but have not been able to get it working so far.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Is there supposed to be a redirect if there is a match with a file?

Comment: technically, no - though we will have 301's for legacy .htm/.html files (yes, they mixed extensions too) which will likely involve something similar, though we know the specific URL's for those.  But for these it is just assuring that if a request is made for a jpg, png or pdf via one of the 'historical' folders from the old site, they find that resource regardless of case - so that they don't end up in the CMS with a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules this way in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/industries/(.+?)\.(jpg|png|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^Industries/ /Industries/%1.%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I will test this out this afternoon and respond back - but wanted to ask about the NE flag, was just reading about it applying 'proxy-nocanon' - but trying to understand the ramification of that, would appreciate your take on what it does here - thanks again

Comment: `NE` is for no encoding the resulting URL.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working straight off - have another case for something similar so between these two responses hopefully I will be able to get that one on my own.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

To not have to worry about case. You need to use the `[NC]` flag for no case. Then it won't matter how it comes in. In this scenario code below. If the URI comes in as say

`http://example.com/Industrial/someimage.jpg`

then it will not do anything. The `NC` flag will still match it. No rewrite is performed.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/industrial/(.+)\.(jpe?g|png|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,NC]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc

Comment: Thanks very much, will try this afternoon - but can I ask  I was thinking that [NC] required the spelling module for some reason, because in the past I have tried it but didn't get it to work as I expected - though my focus was on the filename itself, not the path (i.e. if file is Hello.jpg, and someone requests hello.JPG, etc.) - at what point is the spelling module required vs. [NC]?  Thanks again

Comment: Hello - this is really interesting given the compact nature of the rewrite rule - but it doesn't work for me as is - I was able to get the other answer to work so will checkmark that one but will continue to play with this.  Thanks much for your efforts and the above link